# Nested IF statement in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to put together a batch file which copies a couple of files and starts an excel file. The original batch file I had works fine, but I modified it to try and identify whether the operating system is 32-bit or 64-bit, and to reference the correct folder accordingly.

The steps should be as follows:

1. Identify if the operating system has a "Program Files (x86)" folder. If it does, then the operating system must be 64-bit. If it doesn't then proceed to step 5.
2. If it does have the "Program Files (x86)" folder, then see if there is an "installed.txt" file in folder "c:\Program files (x86)\Auto-BF\"
3. If there is no file, then do the following.

a) create "Auto-BF" Folder in "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\"
b) copy 2 files from "c:\Program files (x86)\Auto-BF" into this newly created "Auto-BF" folder, using a pair of xcopy commands:
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
c) Now create an "installed.txt" file and place it in the ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF" folder to confirm that the folder has been created and the files have been copied.
d) now start an excel spreadsheet "abf.xlsx" from the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF" folder and then exit the batch file.

1. If there is already an "installed.txt" file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF" folder, then simply launch an excel spreadsheet in the same folder "abf.xlsx"

(for 32-bit systems when "Program Files (x86)" does not exist)
5. Check to see if there is an "installed.txt" file in "C:\Program Files\Auto-BF\"

1. If there is no file, then do the following.

a) create "Auto-BF" Folder in "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\"
b) copy 2 files from "c:\Program files\Auto-BF" into this newly created "Auto-BF" folder, using a pair of xcopy commands:
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
c) Now create an "installed.txt" file and place it in the ""C:\Program Files\Auto-BF" folder to confirm that the folder has been created and the files have been copied.
d) now start an excel spreadsheet "abf.xlsx" from the "C:\Program Files\Auto-BF" folder and then exit the batch file.

1. If there is already an "installed.txt" file in "C:\Program Files\Auto-BF" folder, then simply launch an excel spreadsheet in the same folder "abf.xlsx"

Ok I hope that was relatively straightforward to follow! :-)

This is the batch file I've already created, but something isn't quite working right....

---

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%windir%\system32\xcopy.exe"') do set path=%path%;%%~dpa

IF EXIST "c:\Program Files (x86)\" (

cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\"
IF EXIST "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\installed.txt" START abf.xlsx 
IF EXIST "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\installed.txt" EXIT
) ELSE (

REM create Auto-BF Folder
cd %userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\
md Auto-BF

REM move files
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y

cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\

ECHO Auto-BF successfully installed >installed.txt

START abf.xlsx
EXIT )

IF EXIST "c:\Program Files (x86)\" (


cd "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\"
IF EXIST "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\installed.txt" START abf.xlsx 
IF EXIST "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\installed.txt" EXIT
) ELSE (

REM create Auto-BF Folder
cd %userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\
md Auto-BF

REM move files
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y

cd c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\

ECHO Auto-BF successfully installed >installed.txt

START abf.xlsx

EXIT )
```

Comment: please check your `(` and `)`. They are not paired and the logic looks quite weird.

Comment: just made an adjustment (edited above), but still not working...not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: you have one `) ELSE (` to much. (the second one, I think) - that makes a "IF - ELSE - ELSE", what is not possible (in batch).

Comment: tried removing it, but still no joy

Comment: can you please edit the code in your question to the current state? So we can discuss at the same base. (if you removed `) ELSE (` then you removed a `)` to much. And to keep the logic, an `exit` is missing)

Comment: Hi Stephan...thankyou for your help. I have updated the code above to the code I have tried, but this is not working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

both of your IF -constructs are the same:

```
IF EXIST "c:\Program Files (x86)\" (
```

The second one should be:

```
IF EXIST "c:\Program Files\" (
```